# How to create a downloadable zip file with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, zip, browserify, download, electron

I'm currently using electron with nodejs and then using the plugin browserify to make it compatible online to make a website. One of the things I want to do is to have the user upload a file (csv), combine it with a text file that I generate, zip the two up, and then give them a "download zip" option that they can use to download the zip I generated. I would also want all of this to occur client-side.

What I need to happen is again:

1. Generate a text file
2. Have user upload csv
3. Zip the two together
4. Give the user a link to download zip

All client-side.

I've already searched online for methods to do this, but all the ways to implement a download link that I found either require the file to be a text file, or use fs/express or some other plugins that don't seem to work with browserify.

If what I'm asking for isn't possible, let me know so I don't waste time!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at https://stuk.github.io/jszip/. You can create a .zip file with folders and files (file content is a string parameter) with the help of that library. Seems like that should do the trick.

Comment: @leroydev, Would the string zip files be converted to the .zip file format correctly?

Comment: what do you mean? If you're asking if it'll save correctly as a .zip file, you can use https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ for that.

Comment: @leroydev, I'm using it along with browerserify, this is all happening online. I'm not sure I can directly save it onto their computer, I need to provide them a download link.

Comment: @leroydev, nevermind, I got it to work

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to leroydev's response, I was able to generate the zip file using [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/), upload the csv using a form with input type="file" accept=".csv", read the file using FileReader, and then finally save the zipped file by using [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) with [jvsteiner's solution](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/156).

Thanks!